# Tinymce Visual Editor not working after 4.8.2 wordpress updates

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, tinymce, visual-editor

The issue fixed earlier but after WordPress updates again the issue appears. TinyMCE file not loading on WordPress dashboard. I already tried access and flush the cache file. Please let me know if any other function could fix the issue permanently.

For more details, please find the screenshot attached with this question.
[image: Screenshot from Chrome Console]